# Resource file for language dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I have a web application that works in several languages. On the client side, I store words in JavaScript arrays like this:

```
var SomeSectionOfThePage = ['word1', 'word2', ... ]
```

And then when I'm generating the HTML dynamically in the client I do this:

```
var TheHTML = '<div>' + SomeSectionOfThePage[0] + '</div>';
```

I keep the dictionary arrays in a different .js files and when I need to generate the page, the URL for the JavaScript file is resolved according to the user's language. This works great because I don't need to touch the code to modify words in the language dictionaries.

I want to do the same thing for the back-end: I want to have different resource files that get loaded  depending on the user's language.

For now, this is what I'm doing for generating HTML on the server:

```
<div><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="SomeID" /></div>
```

And then in my code-behind, I do something like this:

```
switch (TheLanguage)
{
   case 1:
       SomeID.Text = "hi";

   case 2:
       SomeID.Text = "bonjour";
}
```

As you can see, the text is stored in my C# file and that works well for now but I want to move the text to a resource file. How do I store the words so that they're easy to restore in C# when I generating the HTML? I'm looking for ideas on how to put this functionality together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to start here with this information:

[Localization with Resource Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa992030(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just saw a tutorial on Youtube; looks interesting.